# iOS kill myapp issue

Tags: iphone, ios, background

```
Oct  5 16:23:07  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.gx.uxart[0x57b0]) Exited: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.hahainteractive.bookswing[0x2339]) Exited: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  com.apple.launchd[1] <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.nike.nikeplus-gps[0xf40f]) Exited: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:net.nyvra.NYSliderPopoverDemo[0x43d]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.croquis.CookieWords[0xcc22]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.gx.uxart[0x57b0]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.hahainteractive.bookswing[0x2339]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9

Oct  5 16:23:07  backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.nike.nikeplus-gps[0xf40f]' exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

myapp is com.gx.uxart. I have any questions.

what is com.apple.lanuchd? (I know backboard that is SpringBoard Daemon.)

why kill my app by ios? memory usage?

What can I do to prevent the application killing by iOS? memory optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

launched is the father of all processes.. under unix that was inits IIRC.
it's job is too launch and relaunch and kill daemons/apps including springboard I'd guess

but that doesn't matter in your case :) What matters is that you CANT reliably prevent the OS from killing your app. It can be killed anytime. There is no constant background mode. Apple writes about this in detail:

Any app that goes into bg can REQUEST to continue running via a backgroundTask it starts. Then you can get as much time as you want... in theory. In practice: you shouldn't use memory, cpu time or consume power or you are killed nonetheless.

### speculation

In your case it does indeed look the OS kills as much apps as possible to give more men to nikeplus-gps ... but it isn't enough and so it has to kill nikeplus too

Comment: @downvoter: no problem with getting down voted but as always it'd be nice if you left a comment

Answer (score 0):

How much memory is your app using? Launchd will kill apps if memory pressures arise.

Launch your app with instruments and look at the allocations. Specifically the live bytes. This is surely your problem.

Additionally this assumes your app is the foreground app. If your app is in the background it can be suspended at anytime for many reasons.

Start with Instruments first though, if you haven't already. A good memory footprint is the foundation for avoiding many problems.

**Helpful References:**

- [Using Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)
- [iOS multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)